# Procedure not getting called

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

In the following code if I comment the line `call str_copy` then the procedure
`compare_strings` get's invoked. Otherwise It doesn't.

I tried putting more `WriteString` statements to debug it. But nothing gets printed if `call str_copy` is there. what could be the reason for this?

```
  include irvine32.inc
    
    .data
    string_1 BYTE "abcde////",0
    string_2 BYTE "ABCDE",0
    msg0 BYTE "string_1 in upper case: ",0
    msg1 BYTE "string_1 and string_2 are equal",0
    msg2 BYTE "string_1 and string_2 are equal",0
    msg3 BYTE "string_1 and string_2 are equal",0
    
    source BYTE "AABCDEFGAABCDFG",0 ; size = 15
    target BYTE 20 dup(0)
    
    .code
    main PROC
    mov esi,offset source
    mov edi,offset target
    
    call str_copy
    call compare_strings
    exit
    main ENDP
    
    
    compare_strings PROC
    mov edx,OFFSET msg2 ; string 1 is less than...
    call WriteString
    
    ; Compare string_1 to string_2.
    INVOKE Str_compare, ADDR source, ADDR target
    .IF ZERO?
    mov edx,OFFSET msg1
    .ELSEIF CARRY?
    mov edx,OFFSET msg2 ; string 1 is less than...
    .ELSE
    mov edx,OFFSET msg3 ; string 2 is less than...
    .ENDIF
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    ret
    compare_strings ENDP
    
    END main
```

Comment: One likely reason would be that `str_copy` - which you haven't shown us - contains one or more bugs, or that you're calling it in an incorrect way.

Comment: What do you see when you single step??

Comment: @Michael Str_copy is one of the functions in Irvine.  Looking at the Irvine examples, it should be called like: `INVOKE Str_copy,  ADDR string_1, ADDR string_2`, which (I'm [told](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/invoke?view=msvc-160)) passes parameters on the stack.  Putting values in registers and calling the function directly does not produce the same results, which probably means your code is crashing.

Comment: `INVOKE Str_copy,  ADDR string_1, ADDR string_2` This thing worked. Thanks @DavidWohlferd  I don't know where did I get that `call str_copy` from. Could be that it works in irvine64 and not in irvine32 ?

Comment: So was it like erroring out at that like `call str_copy` silently  previously? Is there a way to detect and see the errors ?

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step it.  That can tell you more than debug-prints, since you can look at FLAGS and other registers and notice things you didn't think to check for.

Comment: ok. There is no way like in normal programming languages to  crash with an exception ?

Comment: Depends. If you have Visual Studio installed and an application crashes, you may get a dialog asking you if you want to launch the Visual Studio debugger, where you at a minimum should be able to see a disassembly and what the register values were. At least that used to be possible in the past; it's been a long time since I used Visual Studio regularly so things might have changed.